# Is it possible to split left and right channel from audio sample in SFML?

Tags: c++, audio, sfml, sample

I am using `const sf::Int16* samples = buffer.getSamples();` to collect all audio samples in an array. My sample.wav file is 16 bits per sample. From [here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) I see that the first 8 bits correspond to the left channel and the latter ones to the right channel.

I'm currently accessing the samples using `samples[i]` but that returns an integer value. How should I proceed to be able to split the channels?

Answer (score 4):

Each sample is a single 16-bit value; it isn't two 8-bit values.

The channels are interleaved.
This means - in a two channel sound sample - that the first sample (16-bit value) is the left channel, the second is the right, the third is the left, the fourth is the right and so on.

The following code splits a single stereo sound buffer (**originalBuffer**) into two separate mono sound buffers (**leftBuffer** and **rightBuffer**):

```
sf::SoundBuffer originalBuffer;
// set up original buffer here - assumed to be stereo during this example
const sf::Int16* originalSamples{ originalBuffer.getSamples() };
const sf::Uint64 sizeOfSingleChannel{ originalBuffer.getSampleCount() / 2u };
sf::Int16* leftSamples{ new sf::Int16[sizeOfSingleChannel] };
sf::Int16* rightSamples{ new sf::Int16[sizeOfSingleChannel] };
for (sf::Uint64 i{ 0u }; i < sizeOfSingleChannel; ++i)
{
    leftSamples[i] = originalSamples[i * 2u];
    rightSamples[i] = originalSamples[i * 2u + 1u];
}
sf::SoundBuffer leftBuffer;
sf::SoundBuffer rightBuffer;
leftBuffer.loadFromSamples(leftSamples, sizeOfSingleChannel, 1u, originalBuffer.getSampleRate());
rightBuffer.loadFromSamples(rightSamples, sizeOfSingleChannel, 1u, originalBuffer.getSampleRate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, using bitwise operators it's easy:

```
int main() {
    uint16_t number = 0xfacb;                                        // decimal: 64203
    uint8_t low_byte = static_cast<uint8_t>(number & 0xFF);          // low byte: 203
    uint8_t high_byte = static_cast<uint8_t>((number & ~0xFF) >> 8); // high byte: 250

    std::cout << std::bitset<16>(number) << " " << std::bitset<8>(high_byte) << " " << std::bitset<8>(low_byte) << "\n"; 
    std::cout << number << " " << static_cast<unsigned short>(high_byte) << " " << static_cast<unsigned short>(low_byte) << "\n"; 
}
```

Remember to assign the result of the bitwise operation to your numeric type of 8 bits.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/553ac7fc674ff7b8).